# disable comment rss

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i am using this to automatic display the rss in the header.php

```
automatic_feed_links();
```

in the header appears feed=rss2 and feed=comments-rss2

now i just want to **disable the comments-rss2** since i dont use comments in the theme.

if i use `remove_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links', 2 );`  both are removed from the head.

I just want to remove the comments-rss2 -
couldnt find any reference how to this.

anyone  know?

Answer (score -1):

**feed_links** function in wp-includes/general-template.php contains **echo** command for both feed and not be able to disable with argument. Comment out **//** this line: (wp-includes/general-template.php #1614 for wp3.1)

`echo '<link rel="alternate" type="' . feed_content_type() . '" title="' . esc_attr(sprintf( $args['comstitle'], get_bloginfo('name'), $args['separator'] )) . '" href="' . get_feed_link( 'comments_' . get_default_feed() ) . "\" />\n";`